# React and Axios dont connect to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nodes

**My code is not working**, i am using node and React, the axios is trying to connect with the backend, but it fail.

When i try the connect in console:
[image of firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX9ev.png)

my code is: frontend/pages/login/index.js

```
import { FiLogIn } from 'react-icons/fi'
import  {Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import api from '../../services/api'
import './styles.css'

export default function Login() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    async function handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        let data = ({
            name,
            password}
        )
        try {
            let response = await api.post('session', data)
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="login-conteiner">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <div className="navlinks">
                        <Link to="/"><div className="li">Vega</div></Link>
                        <Link to="about.html"><div className="li">Sobre</div></Link>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <main className="login">
                <div className="heading">
                    <span className="blackblock"><h1>Vega Leads</h1></span>
                    <h2>Visualize todos os Leads <br /> da sua Instiuição <br /> e torne em alunos.</h2><br />
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <form className="loginForm" id="form" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                            <div className="loginItem"><label htmlFor="login">Login </label><input className="formInput" type="text" name="login" id="login" 
                            value={name} 
                            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} /></div><br />
                            <div className="loginItem"><label htmlFor="senha">Senha </label><input className="formInput" type="password" name="password" id="password" 
                            value={password}
                            onChange={ e => setPassword(e.target.value) } /></div><br />
                            <button type="submit" className="startButton" id="postForm">Enviar <FiLogIn size={25} color="#11548f" /></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    )}
```

Axios api: frontend/services/api.js

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333',
})

export default api
```

If you need more files to resolve my problem, ask me.
Thanks

Comment: Please read this article to get a better understanding of how axios work: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/ you'll find the right way to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem.

the problem is in the index of my backend (backend/src/index.js)

i forget the CORS module.

it is my code:

```
const routes = require('./routes')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(routes)

app.listen(3333)
```